# How to get the full computer name in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to know how to get the Full computer name in Inno Setup, for example `Win8-CL01.cpx.local` in the following image.

[image: windows System computer Name]

I already know how to get the computer name with [GetComputerNameString](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getcomputernamestring) but I also would like to have the Domain name of the computer. How can I get this full computer name or this domain name ?

Comment: You can check the domain with DNS via `GetEnv('UserDnsDomain')`, you can check main domain with `GetEnv('UserDomain')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no built-in function for this in Inno Setup. You can use the [`GetComputerNameEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724301(v=vs.85).aspx) Windows API function:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
#ifdef UNICODE
  #define AW "W"
#else
  #define AW "A"
#endif

const
  ERROR_MORE_DATA = 234;

type
  TComputerNameFormat = (
    ComputerNameNetBIOS,
    ComputerNameDnsHostname,
    ComputerNameDnsDomain,
    ComputerNameDnsFullyQualified,
    ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS,
    ComputerNamePhysicalDnsHostname,
    ComputerNamePhysicalDnsDomain,
    ComputerNamePhysicalDnsFullyQualified,
    ComputerNameMax
  );

function GetComputerNameEx(NameType: TComputerNameFormat; lpBuffer: string; var nSize: DWORD): BOOL;
  external 'GetComputerNameEx{#AW}@kernel32.dll stdcall';

function TryGetComputerName(Format: TComputerNameFormat; out Output: string): Boolean;
var
  BufLen: DWORD;
begin
  Result := False;
  BufLen := 0;
  if not Boolean(GetComputerNameEx(Format, '', BufLen)) and (DLLGetLastError = ERROR_MORE_DATA) then
  begin
    SetLength(Output, BufLen);
    Result := GetComputerNameEx(Format, Output, BufLen);
  end;    
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  Name: string;
begin
  if TryGetComputerName(ComputerNameDnsFullyQualified, Name) then
    MsgBox(Name, mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: However, I'm not sure about the flag used in this example. If it returns you a different name than you want, try to use flags different from `ComputerNameDnsFullyQualified` (I don't have a machine to verify).

Comment: I have checked that on 2 machines in domain and the result is positive.

Comment: @RobeN, thank you! I chose that one according to suggestion from [`this thread`](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/getting-computer-and-domain-name-of-pc.1226600/), but I wasn't sure with it (although, the guy who answered there is from MS support team, so they should be right).

Comment: There is a problem with this solution: the returned string terminates with a null character. Therefore, if you use this string in a `Format` function the result will be truncated at the null character position. In order to remove the null character, you could add the line `SetLength(Output, BufLen);` after calling the function `GetComputerNameEx(Format, Output, BufLen)`. In fact BufLen, "on output, receives the number of TCHARs copied to the destination buffer, not including the terminating null character".

Answer (score 3):

With built-in functions you can get the full name this way:

```
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
    MsgBox(GetComputerNameString + '.' + GetEnv('UserDnsDomain'), mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

Although TLama's solution gives you wider possibilities of further development.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the null-termination problem left over with TLama's solution, you can use the Inno setup Copy function to copy the correct number of characters without the null terminator.

So, in the original answer, replace:

```
Result := GetComputerNameEx(Format, Output, BufLen);
```

with:

```
if (Boolean(GetComputerNameEx(Format, Output, BufLen)) then
begin
    Result := Copy(Output, 1, BufLen);
end;
```